# How to select multiple div by his unique id number

Tags: css, css-selectors

is there a way to select multiple div with css??

like

```
div id="text-box4"
div id="text-box5"
div id="text-box7"
```

etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS doesn't have a wildcard for that.

However if you use jQuery you can:
http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/ or
http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-word-selector/

```
<div id="text-box4"></div>
<div id="text-box5"></div>
<div id="text-box7"></div>
<script>$("div[id*='text-box']").css("color", "red");</script>
```

Comment: ah, tx those numbers are dynamicly rendered by post-id´s. I need to make their height equal to a photo next to it.

Comment: hmm, your suggestion doesn´t seem to work on id="text-box-prod7"
and
<script>$("div[id*='text-box-prod']").css("color", "red");</script>

Comment: no problem, please mark this or one of the other answers as 'the answer'. That makes it easier for other visitors to track.

Comment: Uh... jQuery borrowed this selector from CSS. It's not unique to jQuery.

Answer (score 2):

Native to ie7,ie8 and any other browser that accepts "substring matching attribute selectors" (cf. http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/), you can use the following syntax to select elements with multiple similar ids:

div[id^='text-box']

This basically says to the parsing engine, "select all div elements that have an id attribute which begins with 'text-box'

QRC:

[attribute^='text'] = attributes that STARTS with 'text'

[attribute$='text'] = attributes that END with 'text'

[attribute*='text'] = attributes that CONTAINS 'text'

Answer (score 1):

like this?

```
#text-box4, 
#text-box5, 
#text-box7 {
    /* your properties here */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

CSS classes are designed for selecting multiple elements:

```
<div id="text-box4" class="my-text-box"/>
<div id="text-box5" class="my-text-box"/>
<div id="text-box7" class="my-text-box"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

maerics' answer is correct. The CSS selector used to select the `div`s in that case would be:

```
.my-text-box {
  /* Styles go here */
}
```